# PHP password_verify returns NULL when parameters are the same

Tags: php, mysql, get, password-encryption

I have a problem with PHP function `password_verify`. I've written simple PHP function that uses `_GET`, takes 3 parameters: `$user_unique_id`, `old_password` and `new_password`. It verifies if `old password` and the `password stored in database` are the same. I use `hash` from my database and compare it with `old password` using `password_verify()` fucntion but it returns `false` even whem I'm 100% sure the passwords are the same. Can somebodyb help me with this problem? I've checked `MySQL queries` and all works very well. I return `updated_at` time which later I encode to `JSON`.

This is my function in main script `changeuserpassword.php` I call from link:

```
<?php
require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// JSON Response Array
$response = array();

// Receiving The Post Params
$old_password = $_GET['old_password'];
$new_password = $_GET['new_password'];
$user_unique_id = $_GET['user_unique_id'];

// Change User Password
$user = $db->changeUserPassword($user_unique_id, $old_password, $new_password);

if ($user != false) {
    $response["error"] = false;
    $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    $response["error"] = true;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Podano nieprawidłowe stare hasło";
    echo json_encode($response);    
}
?>
```

This is the function I use in `changeuserpassword.php` main script. It is called `changeUserPassword`:

```
/**
 * Change User Account Password
 */
public function changeUserPassword($user_unique_id, $old_password, $new_password) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT user.`encrypted_password` 
                                    FROM `user` 
                                    WHERE user.`unique_id` = ?");   // Preparing SELECT Query To The `user` Table
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $user_unique_id);                        // Binding With Params

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc(); // Fetching Rows From Query
        $stmt->close();

        $password_hash = $user["encrypted_password"];   // Decrypting Hashed Password

        // Checking Currrent Password Identity With Decrypted Password
        if (password_verify($old_password, $password_hash)) {   // Old Password And Current One Are The Same
            $encrypted_password = password_hash($new_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);   // Hashing New Password

            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE user 
                                            SET user.`encrypted_password` = ?, user.`updated_at` = NOW() 
                                            WHERE user.`unique_id` = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("ss", $encrypted_password, $user_unique_id);
            $result = $stmt->execute();
            $stmt-close();

            // Checking For Succesfull UPDATE
            if ($result) {
                $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT user.`updated_at` 
                                                FROM `user` 
                                                WHERE user.`unique_id` = ?");
                $stmt->bind_param("s", $user_unique_id);
                $stmt->execute();
                $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc(); // Fetching Rows From Query
                $stmt->close();

                return $user;
            }
        } else {    // Old Password And Current One Are Different
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Here is my database screenshot:
[image]
My script runs but it always return false which means `password_verify()` returns false.

**Solved**

The problem was `$stmt->close()` statement. I used them too often and thats why the script didn't work.

Comment: sidenote: why are you using `$_GET['new_password']` and not POST? that not so safe.

Comment: I am using it with Google's Volley? I am just a begginer. Any idae how can do it "safely" using Java?

Comment: sorry, I don't know any java.

Comment: Are you decrypting the hashed values or just using the same algorithm to hash the same value and comparing those for quality?

Comment: How does your SQL table look like? have you made the field to save the hashed password long enough? It should be 255 in length when you are using the method you use.

Comment: Are you sure the $_GET data is actually being passed to this script?

Comment: check for errors on PHP and your query. make sure the password column is actually long enough to hold the hash. If it isn't, you'll need to start over and using a longer length for it.

Comment: @CelebE Yes, I use `password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)`. @urulke I gave that field 255 characters - pls. check my edit for screenshot from my SQL database.

Comment: @anton86993 see my answer.

Comment: Could you please try to make a new php script and just run `if(password_verify('Plaintext', 'hashed')){echo 'yay';}´ and put your plaintext password and hashed inside it. By doing this we can check if the problem is some escaping of characters.

Comment: @anton86993, Have you tried to just echo out the hashedpasword to check if you get the correct output?

Comment: I am back. Yes I am going to try in a minute.

Comment: Use this: http://anton869.linuxpl.eu/android_login_api/test_verify.php . I generated hash then chekced it with password via `verify_password`. All works.

Comment: @anton86993, Okay, try escaping your input password http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php 
Also have you checked if it fetches the correct hashed password from your database?

Comment: In the link you send you are hashing the password, try just taking the raw hashed data directly from database and see if that matches your password.

Comment: I forogot to say that I've added in class constructor: `$this->conn->set_charset("utf8"); // Setting Charset To UTF-8` May that be a problem? I used it cause couldn't get correct results form queries (there were problems with encoding).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96937/discussion-between-uruloke-and-anton86993).

Comment: I have solved the problem. I used too many `$stmt->close()` that's why it closed. Speciall thanks to @uruloke for helping me solving this problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging with @anton86993 in a chat, we found the bug to be the use of too many `$sql->close()` statements, when they weren't needed.

There is no reason to have that many close statements, as PHP automatically closes the connection to SQL when the script is done. A reason to have a close statement could be to release a connection to SQL, if you have a limited amount of connection at once or the obvious one to release resources.